# Update fragment of ViewPage with Web Service response

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am new to FragmentActivity, Fragment and ViewPager.

I am using FragmentActivity with 2 Fragments.

Each fragment is using the same data which I will get from web service call in AsyncTask.

Now I don't want to call the Web Service twice for each fragment.

Rather my idea is to get the data from Web Service using AsyncTask in FragmentActivity & then notify the FragmentAdapter that data has been received. So accordingly Adapter should update the view of both Fragment.

But I am stuck with how to achieve this. It would be great if anyone suggest me the way or some examples like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start a task in background and when result is received notify the fragments like this

```
package com.example.myapplication2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity3 extends ActionBarActivity {


    private FragmentManager fragManager;
    private Fragment fragOne,fragTwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if((fragOne=fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_one))==null){
        fragOne = new FragOne();
        fragManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragOne )
                .commit();
    }
    if((fragTwo=fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_two))==null){
        fragTwo = new FragTwo();
        fragManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragTwo)
                .commit();
    }

    startTaskInBackground();

    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete() {
    fragOne.onDataReceived();
    fragTwo.onDataReceived();
    }


}
```

Comment: i  faced same problem... anyone have solution of this problem... using volley library....  @Rajesh Batth